# I'm unable to get JSON data on the page after Interpolation in Ionic 2

Tags: json, api, angular, ionic2

I'm very new to Ionic 2 and i've found myself stuck with an issue. I'm unable to see the data printing on the page, it throws an error everytime, but I'm able to see the API call being a success in the console log. My code looks something like this

> moviedetails.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {MBService} from '../../app/services/moviebuffs.service';


@Component({
selector: 'page-moviedetails',
templateUrl: 'moviedetails.html'
})
export class MoviedetailsPage {
id: any;
md: any;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private moviebuffsService: MBService) {
    this.navCtrl = navCtrl;
    this.id = navParams.get('param1');
    this.getMovieDetails(this.id);

   }

  getMovieDetails(mid){
this.moviebuffsService.getMovieDetails(mid).subscribe(response => {
     console.log(response);
        this.md = response;
});
}

}
```

The response for title comes up in the console with no issues, but there's an error when i try calling it through the html file.

```
Runtime Error
Error in ./MoviedetailsPage class MoviedetailsPage - caused by: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

In my html i call the object as **{{md.title}}** What am i doing wrong? Is it because i declared the function inside the constructor?

Comment: U need to initialise `md`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `md` field is initialized asynchronously in your code. So if the template renders before the response arrives: `undefined`.`title` will throw an error.

Either initialize your object,

```
md: any = {};
```

or use the safe-navigation operator (`?`),

```
 {{md?.title}}
```

or use an `*ngIf` to check whether your object is valid or not,

```
<div *ngIf="md">
    {{md.title}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! You're a life saver! :) I put  `md: any = {};` and it works like a charm.

Comment: @RahulPrabhakar no problem. My suggestion would be to use the 2nd one tho because if it's a nested object like `md.title.name` it will again throw an error  :-)

Comment: I've gone ahead with the second option, works fine too. :)