# Angular2 Display data

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic2

I am just trying to display some information that I get into my API by a service but, I can't access to it in my view while the console show me the info that I need.

my angular service

```
getById(id){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        this.http.get(this.urlRoot+'entreprise/'+id, {headers:headers})
            .subscribe(res=>{
                let data = res.json();
                resolve(data.entreprise);
            }, (err) =>{
                reject(err)
            })
    })

  }
```

my view code sample

```
<div class="entreprise-name"><h1> {{ entreprise.name }} </h1></div>
```

the error code

```
Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

the API json answere

```
{
  "entreprise": {
    "id": 1,
    "domaine_id": 1,
    "category_id": 1,
    "name": "Culry Hairs",
    "location": "Rue du Travail 1, 7000 Mons, Belgium",
    "description": "La coupe qui décoiffe",
    "contact_person": "Marie Kristy",
    "phone_number": "065/53.46.55",
    "createdAt": "2017-03-05T23:00:00.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2017-03-05T23:00:00.000Z"
  }
}
```

[img of the 'console.log' of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZMkV.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm unable to get JSON data on the page after Interpolation in Ionic 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630452/im-unable-to-get-json-data-on-the-page-after-interpolation-in-ionic-2)

Comment: Object will be undefined  Please add  *ngIf="entreprise" to div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because Angular is trying to show the properties of entreprise, while it has not received the object yet.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Use `*ngIf="entreprise"` inside the `<div>`, to show the content only if `entreprise` is not `null`. Inside the `<div>` then you can access safely to all its properties (id, name...). Following your sample, it would be:

   `<div class="entreprise-name" *ngIf="entreprise"><h1> {{ entreprise.name }} </h1></div>`
2. Use the **safe navigation operator** (also called *Elvis operator*), and it is represented by symbol **?**. This will prevent Angular 2 to rending the propierty until `entreprise != undefined`. To use it, following your sample, it would be:

   `<div class="entreprise-name"><h1> {{ entreprise?.name }} </h1></div>`

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you a lot @AMarquez94 !

The *ngIf solution kept me in struggle because, every bind info was hidden and didn't appear even when the page was loaded. 

But you learned me something with the Elvis Operator and it work great !

Thank again.

Answer (score 0):

add `*ngIf="entreprise"` to the `div`